# How do I compare variables between a scriptlet and JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have JSP code of the form

```
<%
    int count = 1;
    request.setAttribute("count", count);
%>
<c:set var="max" scope="request" value="${100}" />
<c:if test="${request.getAttribute('count') < max}" >
  ...
</c:if>
```

That is, the `test` compares a variable defined in a scriptlet to a variable defined using `<c:set>`.  The code fails with an error thrown at the line of the `test` condition.  I've tried all kinds of variations on this, and I can't find anything online that explains the interaction between scriptlets and JSP EL clearly enough for me to figure out what I should do here.

How do I compare a scriptlet variable to a JSTL variable using JSTL?

**Edit** The error thrown is

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page
```

I assume that's as useless as it sounds, but there it is in case it means anything to anyone.

Comment: You can directly access the `count`  because you already set it in request scope. `test="${count < max}"` or `test="${requestScope.count < max}"`.

Comment: it is not recommended to use java code inside jsp.Try to use jstl.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt I can confirm that both of those work. Make it an answer, and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly access the count variable because you already set it in the request scope:

`test="${count < max}"` or `test="${requestScope.count < max}"`